# Changing .avi file in to .mp4 file

Tags: rendering, file-format

So I've already rendered an animation as an .avi file, is there some way to change the file to .mp4 without rendering the animation again?

Answer (score 1):

This is off the Blender topic and rather belongs to https://video.stackexchange.com

How you want to use your video should drive what format and quality you need.

If you are comfortable with command line tools, I suggest ffmpeg  (https://www.ffmpeg.org). The dead simple answer is `ffmpeg -i "input.avi" "output.mp4"` though this will reencode it and you will loose some quality. If the video stream inside your AVI is h.264 or other MP4 compatible encoding, you can rewrap without quality loss using `ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -c:v copy -c:a copy "output.mp4"`.

Comment: While video encoding tools like ffmpeg will be easier, you can add your movie to the [VSE](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/introduction.html) and render with new settings, this will be much quicker than the original rendering as it will only compress the video to the new settings.

Comment: @sambler, good idea to use Blender which actually includes ffmpeg as video encoding engine. Though not sure how much access to all ffmpeg settings are avail from Blender.